# Require.js not compiling single js file correctly

Tags: requirejs

I'm trying to build my require.js modules to one javascript file for production.

The command I'm running is...

```
r.js -o name=main out=main.min.js mainConfigFile=main.js
```

This compiles but the compiled main.min.js file is not compiled correctly and still includes the "define" statement blocks. and the browser obviously returns

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

My main.js file looks like:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
    },
    shim: {
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'jquery'
        }
    }
});
require(['app', 'jquery'], function (app, $) {
    'use strict';
    // use app here
    console.log(app);
    console.log('Running jQuery %s', $().jquery);
});
```

Please let me know what I'm overlooking here.
Thanks!

Comment: May have worked it out... I've included require.js in the build. eg r.js -o name=main out=main.min.js mainConfigFile=main.js include=libs/requirejs/require.js is that right though?

Comment: You're correct that RequireJS must also be included in the minified file.

Also, if you're concerned with reducing the size of your minified js file, try using Almond.  It's a tiny alternative loader by the same author as RequireJS that's designed for use in minified production builds.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're correct, you need to include requireJS in your build. Take a look at http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#onejs. You'll find an example for the command line there. If you're using a build profile it will look something like this -

```
({
baseUrl: "../Scripts",
paths: {
    requireLib: 'libs/require'
},
name: "main",
out: "main-built.js",
include: ["requireLib"]
})
```

Comment: total lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick fix:** use `r.js -o build.js` instead of `node r.js -o build.js`

---

I had the problem when I was trying to call `r.js` through node:

`node r.js -o build.js`

Calling `r.js` directly fixed the problem:

`r.js -o build.js`

*Note: `r.js` was installed globally with `npm install -g requirejs`*