# Are Asynchronous Modules Always Asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, commonjs, browserify

When multiple JavaScript modules are `define()'d` using AMD and concatenated into a single file, are those modules still considered asynchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are still considered async.

While the module itself doesn't have to be loaded from disk, the modules do need to be executed and there is a call back made.

Because you can combine *SOME* modules into a single file doesn't mean you have to combine all -- nor does RequireJS assume all there.

It will run what it can from your preload and async load the rest.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Do you know when the module is considered to be "in memory" (i.e., when it's loaded vs. when it's executed)?

Comment: You can't assume a module has been loaded until you get the callback.  If you need a module, make sure you always use it in your `require` or `define` statement -- if you rely upon something earlier in the chain loading it you can run into race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, just concatenating a bunch of AMD modules together won't make them synchronous. However, if you can live with additional limitations and select a loader that can do it, you can load AMD modules synchronously.

#### RequireJS

I don't know of a case where RequireJS will load anything synchronously, even if asynchronous loading is not needed. You could have the following in a `<script>` tag:

```
define("foo", [], function () {
});

require(["foo"], function (foo) {
});
```

There is nothing to load here because all the code is already present there. The `foo` module does not need to be fetched from anywhere. It's list of dependencies is known, etc. Yet, RequireJS will handle it asynchronously.

One source of confusion for some wondering about RequireJS' capability to load modules synchronously could be RequireJS' synchronous form of `require`. You can do:

```
define(function(require) {
    var foo = require("foo");
});
```

The call to `require` here looks like it is synchronous but RequireJS transforms it behind the scenes into this, by adding `"foo"` to the list of `define`'s required modules:

```
define(["foo"], function(require) {
    var foo = require("foo");
});
```

So while the `require` call looks synchronous, RequireJS still handles it asynchronously.

#### Almond

[Almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) is a loader made by James Burke, who is also the author of RequireJS, that can load AMD modules synchronously. Now, Almond comes with a series of limitations. One such limitation is that you can't load anything dynamically. That is, the entire list of modules you want to load has to be part of the optimized bundle you create with `r.js` and give to almond for loading. If you can live with the limitations of almond, then it is quite possible to load a bunch of AMD modules synchronously. I've provided details on how to do this in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22239468/1906307).

Comment: Thanks for the great detail. Would the memory footprint of the program be affected by whether sync/async is used (again assuming all modules are already present in the file)?

Comment: The only difference I would see between the sync and the async scenario is the size of the loader. Almond is much smaller than RequireJS.